# Propuesta de cambio etiqueta [array] por [arrays]

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Eso, acabo de publicar una pregunta y he visto que no existe la etiqueta [arrays](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays), sino que es **[array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array).**

Creo que tiene mas sentido en plural, ya que la etiqueta no se refiere a un array concreto, sino al tema general, y por lo tanto, (entiendo) que debe ser en plural quedando [arrays](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays).

¿Que os parece?

PD: publicando esta pregunta he visto que existe en meta [discusion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discusion) y [discussion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion).... ¿No deberíamos unificar esto también?

Comment: Más que un cambio ¿un sinónimo no bastaría?

Comment: Mejor que no existe [discusion]... en vez necesitamos [discusión].

Comment: @dwarandae pues la verdad es que puede ser que si, no tengo mucha experiencia con los tags, pero suena bastante bien :). Basicamente creo que mientras ayude a los users a encontrar mas facil los temas, sera un beneficio para todos.

Comment: ¿Tal vez necesitemos `arreglo` como sinónimo también?.