# Esto necesita arreglarse desde la matriz

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Tenemos las etiquetas:

- [array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array)

  - No. de preguntas: 390
  - Wiki de etiqueta: Sí
- [arreglos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arreglos)

  - No. de preguntas: 48
  - Wiki de etiqueta: Sí
- [matrices](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matrices)

  - No. de preguntas: 61
  - Wiki de etiqueta: No

En la jerga informática es bastante común el uso de `arreglo` como traducción de `array`, pero en matemáticas se utiliza `matriz`. Siendo que matemáticas e informática tienen un fuerte vínculo muchos lo consideran como sinónimos.

Ahora bien ¿Estamos usando [array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array), [arreglos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arreglos) y [matrices](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matrices) para cosas diferentes o son lo mismo? ¿Deberían ser sinónimos? ¿Cuál debería ser la etiqueta principal?

**Preguntas en Meta relacionadas**

- [Edición sugerida por tener una palabra en inglés, pero de uso habitual (array)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/700/65)
- [Propuesta de cambio etiqueta [array] por [arrays]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285/65)

Comment: `array` y `arreglo` es lo mismo. `matriz` es diferente pues tiene un conjunto propio de operaciones (matematicas), al igual que `vector` son entidades separadas con su propia semantica. Ej cuando se habla de matrices en la jerga de machine learning no tiene nada que ver con arrays, sino con matrices mxn para hacer un calculo determinado.

Comment: Creo que dependiendo del lenguaje, `array` y `vector` pueden ser equivalentes

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro correcto, pero los vectores tienen operaciones diferentes. Es posible multiplicar dos vectores para obtener un tercero (lo mismo con matrices y entre ellos). Esas operaciones no son aplicables a un array. Una matriz y un vector serian otra cosa.

Comment: Me parece que tiene mucha lógica el razonamiento de @EmanuelVe... [tag:array] debería ser sinónimo de [tag:arreglo] (aunque a mi me guste más hablar de arrays que de arreglos, estamos en SOes), y matriz y vector cosas distintas. Dicho esto, hay unas cuantas preguntas en [tag:matrices] que necesitan retag (por qué el plural ahí? no debería ser matriz?)

Comment: @EmanuelVe: En ciertos contextos, array, arreglo y matriz son lo mismo. Aquí el detalle es que [tag:matrices] no tiene wiki de etiqueta. ¿Te animarías a agregar la wiki para dicha etiqueta?

Comment: @Rubén listo, pero falta la revision de pares.

Comment: @EmanuelVe Mil gracias.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Si bien `arreglo` es el término en español hay que tomar en cuenta las estadísticas que indican que el término `array` es mas común y opino que esa sea la etiqueta maestra.

Los sinónimos podrían incluir:

- arrays
- arreglo
- arreglos

Matriz es un término diferente, generalmente usado cuando se tiene un arreglo multidimensional usualmente de 2 dimensiones o en los lenguajes en los que no se soporta a arreglos de arreglos. No debemos mezclar este caso con el caso mas general de arrays o arreglos

Comment: Yo estoy de acuerdo que `array` sea la etiqueta maestra y que `matriz` se una etiqueta independiente.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo. Además no entiendo porque se traduce array pero no hablamos nunca de bucles "mientras" o similar. En mi día a día siempre he escuchado "array" y solamente en internet y por lo general con usuarios americanos he escuchado la palabra "arreglo" para referirse a los arrays.

Por tanto creo que la mejor propuesta es la de usar `array` como etiqueta maestra.

Comment: He realizado la propuesta de que [tag:arreglos] sea sinónimo de [tag:array]. A esperar los votos -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/array/synonyms. [tag:arreglo] no existe como etiqueta.