# [Reflexion]emos un poco sobre [reflection]

Tags: soporte, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado

He visto que tenemos dos lindas etiquetas: [reflection](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflection) y [reflexión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflexi%c3%b3n). Me parece que deberíamos tener solo una de estas etiquetas en el sitio. Como es clásico, suele quedar la etiqueta en español. Aunque antes que nada, quisiera que la comunidad decida cuál sería la mejor. En mi opinión, si bien reflexión sería el término apropiado en español, considero que reflection es un término más usado en la comunicación entre desarrolladores (similar a array vs arreglo).

De todas maneras, lanzo la duda y que se inicie el debate.

Comment: Relacionado: [Esto necesita arreglarse desde la matriz](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2590/65) (discusión sobre array, arreglos y matrices)

Comment: @Rubén no tanto, solo es una coincidencia.

Comment: En lo que se refiere a las etiquetas de este pregunta, me parece que en lugar de `soporte` debería usarse `discusión` pues no se hace una pregunta, ni solicitud de acción por parte de alguien con mayores privilegios, pero se invita a debatir. Tampoco debería incluirse `solicitud-de-quemado` por lo mencionado previamente.

Comment: @Rubén no me importa tanto el debate, sino que una de las dos se queme. Por eso no es discusión. Pero el resultado de cuál quemar es problema a resolver de la comunidad (lo cual siempre genera debate porque sí)

Comment: ¿Por qué quemar en lugar de hacer sinónimo una de la otra?

Comment: @Rubén para que una sí exista y la otra, simplemente **no**.

Answer (score 4):

## Reflexión

Llevo toda la vida usando array y no he empezado a usar arreglo hasta que entré en este sitio. Comprendo que haya quien pueda preferir los términos ingleses por serles más familiares.
Pero este es un claro ejemplo en que usar la palabra en español no causa ninguna confusión dada su gran similitud a la inglesa. Y dado que no hay otros conceptos que sea fácil de asociar erróneamente con esta palabra.

En cuanto al quemado, NO. Una cosa es preferir la palabra en castellano y otra obligar a ello. Dejemos las etiquetas como sinónimos.

Comment: Reflexionemos sobre el código. Reflexiona sobre tus ideas. Reflexión de la luz en el agua. Y así... Mientras que reflection permite acceder a información de las clases, atributos, métodos, anotaciones, etc.

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ ¿De verdad piensas que la palabra reflexión usada en SOes, es decir en un contexto de programación, va a ser fácilmente asociada con la reflexión de la luz en el agua antes que con la capacidad que tiene un programa para observar y opcionalmente modificar su estructura de alto nivel? Quizás debiera añadir a mi respuesta "excepto por aquellos que se empeñen innecesariamente en malinterpretarla a propósito".

Comment: En realidad, ni siquiera en SOes veo el uso de reflexión, lo veo muy minimizado. Es má, tú que programas en Java igual que yo, sabes que el paquete para usar reflection se llama `java.lang.reflect` que apunta a reflection, no reflexión. Y no, no considero en absoluto el uso de la palabra en español. Hay excepciones a la regla y creo con vehemencia que este es uno de esos casos.

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ Si el nombre del paquete en java fuese un argumento en el que realmente creyeses entonces usarías la expresión "Java language" ¿Lo haces o prefieres usar las expresión "Lenguaje java"?

Comment: Prefiero usar PL (programming language) a LP (lenguaje de programación). Prefiero usar lambda expression a expresión lambda. Prefiero usar regexes a decir/escribir expresiones regulares. Y así con muchos términos más. Porque así lo aprendí, porque así lo encuentro más sencillo de entender y comprender. Porque así lo enseñan. Porque esos términos en inglés, nos guste o no, son los que se convierten en parte natural de la programación. Y si hablo con alguien usando el inglés como lenguaje intermedio p.e. un francés, ruso o chino, diciendo los términos en inglés nos comprenderemos.

Answer (score 4):

Yo personalmente uso en su mayoría términos en inglés, y estoy mas acostumbrado a "reflection". Reflexión me suena poco natural, pero entiendo que el debate este abierto (de hecho, en el chat ya se ha tratado en algunas ocasiones el tema).

En mi opinión, nos guste o no el inglés es el lenguaje tecnológico. Podemos utilizar "arreglo", pero al final, cuando vas a programar, la clase que utilizarás es `Array`(en .NET),puedes hablar de "reflexión" pero la clase que usarás es `Reflection` ,etc... y por eso no termina de convencerme la ambigüedad de términos en inglés y español.

En cuanto a la pregunta, yo opino como Jose Antonio Dura Olmos. Ya que considero muy difícil que haya un consenso,me parece más logico que ambas etiquetas sean sinónimos.

Answer (score 4):

#### Problema.

La falta de documentación sobre programación en Español, hasta donde yo se, es un lamento común en la comunidad Hispanohablante de desarrolladores. Esto lleva a la comunidad a utilizar terminología en Inglés aún cuando existen términos perfectamente válidos en Español para referirse al mismo concepto.

1. Entiendo perfectamente que la comunidad use la terminología en Inglés por la abrumadora cantidad de información en dicho idioma; también por la facilidad de comunicar conceptos con otros desarrolladores en base a un conocimiento común.
2. Pero también entiendo perfectamente la frustración de no encontrar documentación escrita en el idioma que te resulta más cómodo.

#### Solución.

En mi opinión, la única manera de solucionar el segundo punto es eliminando el primero, cuantos más conceptos de programación se estudien, debatan, compartan y asimilen en Español, más se abrirá la programación a los Hispanohablantes y más contenido de programación se creará en Español.

Por eso abogo ahora y siempre, en el uso de terminología en Español, siempre que exista un equivalente en Español y si no existe: acuñar el término ¡tenemos la oportunidad de ser pioneros!<sup>1</sup>.

#### Debate.

Pero esto no puede hacerse [al tuntún](http://es.thefreedictionary.com/tunt%c3%ban), requiere una reflexión y análisis; por eso estos debates son tan interesantes y necesarios. En mi opinión [reflexión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflexi%c3%b3n) no debería ser la etiqueta sinónima de [reflection](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflection).

El concepto de Reflection está ligado a la introspección, en este caso el concepto está ligado a el análisis de un objeto en base a unas características que él mismo puede observar, como si observase su reflejo en un espejo. Es por eso que yo sugiero la etiqueta [reflejo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflejo).

#### Sinónimo.

Sea cual sea la palabra utilizada para describir el concepto, considero necesario que la etiqueta con el mismo concepto en Inglés sea marcada como sinónima.

---

<sup>1</sup>Me autoproclamo pionero en acuñar el término [FESNEO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=FESNEUE) o FASNEUE.

Comment: Veo difícil que alguno atine a usar `reflejo` como etiqueta en dichas preguntas. Es como usar una etiqueta `trasformar` para [`casting`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/casting/info) o para [`cast`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/cast/info) :)

Comment: Yo tampoco usaría [tag:transformar] para referirme a [tag:cast]; usaría [tag:convertir]. En mi opinión [tag:reflejo] se ajusta más al significado original de [tag:reflection].

Comment: Yo me quedaría con reflexión: *acción y efecto de reflejar o reflejarse*, según la RAE, pero además hace referencia al concepto matemático: las operaciones/relaciones reflexivas (A- > A) en oposición a las operaciones transitivas (A -> B). Por lo demás estoy de acuerdo: quememos *reflection*, las palabras se parecen lo suficiente como para que cualquiera que quiera usar la etiqueta la encuentre con el autocompletado