# la etiqueta reflection debería de ser sinónimo de reflection

Tags: soporte, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Estoy consciente de que ya se [había discutido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2727/reflexionemos-un-poco-sobre-reflection) y dado que dos de las tres respuestas opinan que sean sinónimos me gustaría oficialmente hacer la petición de convertirlos en sinónimos, pues me confunde no saber cual usar al preguntar acerca de ello.

Sinónimo propuesto: [reflexión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflexi%c3%b3n) ← [reflection](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflection)

Comment: Favor de revisar [¿Cuáles son los pasos a seguir en la creación de un sinónimo de etiqueta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3064/65)

Comment: Nunguna tiene voto definitivo o voto positivo, por eso pregunté acá

Comment: la pregunta si tiene votos positivos y el OP plantea formas en las que piensa que se podría realizar el proceso creación de sinónimos. Sería bueno que todos los que solicitamos apoyo para la creación de sinónimos al menos conozcamos ese hilo.

Comment: la pregunta sí, pero las respuestas no, así que no hay consenso

Comment: Me parece bien la propuesta, pero habiendo **tan** pocas preguntas etiquetadas [tag:reflection] (12 actualmente), ¿No te parece más sencillo reetiquetar a mano? ¿O hay algo por lo que valga la pena que sean sinónimos que no estoy considerando?

Comment: @Rubén efectivamente es bueno conocer ese hilo sobre los pasos a seguir en la creación de un sinónimo de etiqueta, pero hasta que los moderadores o el CM no lo validen, creo correcto hacer una pregunta como esta que hizo Ruslan.

Comment: @fedorqui Me parece que antes de seguir hablando del hilo que dejé en mi primer comentario primero se debería arreglar el título de esta pregunta :)

Comment: @Rubén jaja no me había fijado. Es un título recursivo, que se refleja en sí mismo, casi un palíndromo... jajaja

Comment: Otra cosa no me queda claro si lo correcto es `reflexión` o `reflejo`. Pareciera que aún no hay "consenso" al respecto.