# Hacer arreglos sinónimo de array

Tags: soporte, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Arreglos es el término en español de array. En [Esto necesita arreglarse desde la matriz](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2590/65) se discutió cuál es el que debe usarse como etiqueta maestra y la única respuesta propone usar [array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array) como maestra.

[array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array) ← [arreglos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arreglos)

En la página de sinónimos de array actualmente hay 3 votos a favor. Requerimos de un voto más de algunos de los usuarios con 5 puntos y 2,500 (dos mil quinientos) de rep en dicha etiqueta o bien la intervención de un moderador diamantado.

### Edicion

Vector es una acepción valida tambien para un array. Se analizaron las preguntas que contenian ese tag, y hablan sobre este mismo tema.

[array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array) ← [vector](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vector)

Comment: Ya ha sido creado el sinónimo. Un saludo

Comment: Aca un array es un vector.. pero me parece que es demasiado localizado.. solo esperemos que nadie escriba vector como etiqueta...

Comment: @gbianchi: Ya existe [tag:vector] y tiene 18 preguntas (en este momento, claro)

Comment: ni me habia fijado.. dejame que chequee si las preguntas correspones a array y deberiamos si no hacerla sinonimo tambien..

Comment: No se si conviene eliminar directamente vector como etiqueta, y rezar porque nadie la vuelva a usar (cosa que no parece factible) o agregarla como sinonimo.. efectivamente hablan de array (en su mayoria, no entre a las 18)

Comment: @gbianchi: Si se usa para otras cosas, habría que valorar si esas otras tienen sentido que tengan una etiqueta llamada vector o si en lugar de esta deberían usar otra etiqueta.

Comment: bueno dame 15 min que entro una por una a todas jajja...

Comment: @Rubén Listo, ahora hay 16 preguntas y hablan efectivamente sobre arreglos, array, vectores :) deberian ser sinonimos.

Comment: Listo tambien el `array <--- vector`

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias :)

Comment: Quizás yo sea de la vieja escuela, pero cuando yo lo estudié array != vector. Uno es estático mientras que el otro es dinámico y, aunque se podían acceder igual, se asignaban y trataban de forma diferente.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Cuando lo estudiaste ¿en qué contexto lo hiciste? ¿Era sobre algún lenguaje o desde alguna disciplina en particular?

Comment: @Rubén era como parte de Programación I. El curso era una introducción a la programación estructurada usando Pascal y C como base. Entonces por ejemplo diferenciábamos entre un char[n] y un char*.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Gracias, me parece interesante. Habría que ver si esa distinción es importante en las preguntas que tenemos en el sitio. Las que recuerdo haber visto con la etiqueta vector se referían a array. Por cierto, yo ví el tema de vectores en en las clases de Mecánica, Electricidad y Control pero se referían a cosas muy diferentes, jeje:)

Comment: @Rubén ¿de los de origen, fuerza, dirección y sentido?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro  en lugar de fuerza diría magnitud para generalizar, pero sí, de esos